# How does the CLR interpret the following LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

i have 2 lists of `obj1` and `obj2`

```
var list1 = new List<obj1>();
var list2 = new List<obj2>();
```

obj1 and obj2 share a string property called name, i need to filter list1 by the name property values that are available in list2 so i did the following

```
var filteredlist = list1.Where(o => list2.Select(o2 => o2.name)
                                         .Distinct()
                                         .Contains(o.name));
```

is the above Linq query equivelent to the following?

```
 var distinctNames = list2.Select(o2 => o2.name).Distinct();
 var filteredlist = list1.Where(o => distinctNames.Contains(o.name));
```

my question is in the first query does the clr make a temp variable to hold distinctNames even if i didn't create it myself like in the second query? or will it redo the Select Distinct from list2 with every iteration?

if it doesn't create a temp variable how would you write this query in one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ is only a set of extension methods defined on the `IEnumerable` interface, therefore it is not a question of "how does the CLR do this". Your LINQ query would be equivalent to

```
Func<bool> innerAction = list2.Select(o2 => o2.name).Distinct().Contains(o => o.name);
foreach(var e1 in list1)
{
    bool condition = innerAction();
    if (condition)
    {
        yield return e1;
    }
}
```

The select query will then be something like

```
Func<TIn, TOut> selectFunction = e => e.name;
foreach(var e2 in list2)
{
    yield return selectFunction(e2);
}
```

The results will be passed to the distinct function, which is another `foreach` loop, and that will be passed to the `contains` function, which will result in just another `foreach` loop.

So the answer to your question is "yes, they are more or less equivalent", but it involves a lot of lambdas :) And "yes, it will redo the `Distinct` on every iteration", because it calls the generated lambda again. You'd better force the evaluation of the `innerAction` from my first listing by `ToArray()` or `ToList()` (in your case, call it on the inner action of the where condition).

Answer (score 2):

Matten's answer is completely right, however, I would like to point out, that there is a simple way to ensure that the `Distinct` isn't done over and over again. All you have to do is force the `IEnumerable` into the actual data first, ie.:

```
var distinctNames = list2.Select(o2 => o2.name).Distinct().ToList();
var filteredlist = list1.Where(o => distinctNames.Contains(o.name));
```

And of course, searching in a list is a linear operation, so in the worst case, you're doing `distinctNames.Length * list1.Length` comparisons. If you use a dictionary instead:

```
var distinctNames = list2.GroupBy(i => i.name).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => true);
var filteredList = list1.Where(i => distinctNames.ContainsKey(i.name));
```

Voilá, now the lookup is done in something closer to n * log(n) time :) However, note that this only makes sense if `list1` is not significantly smaller than `list2` - in that case, building the dictionary may very well offset the performance gains later. Always use the right tool for the job :P

Answer (score 1):

LINQ (to objects) is essentially a framework of extension methods to build a combination of functional expressions, which get a applied on a sequence of values, which are represented by a `IEnumerable<T1>` in the .Net Library. The CLR does not need to know about this: For the CLR LINQ is just lambdas and extension-methods.

What is interesting for your question, is how the execution flow is during a LINQ query. In both of your cases, no execution takes place at all. A LINQ query get not evaluated till the resulting `IEnumerable<T2>` is iterated. This also means, that in both cases the query for distinct names is evaluated.

I think it is not possible to prevent this evaluation in the extension method syntax. But is possible to to something like this:

```
var distinctNames = list2.Select(o2 => o2.name).Distinct().ToArray();
var filteredlist = list1.Where(o => distinctNames.Contains(o.name));
```

Or you could try to use the LINQ query syntax with a let-statement. But I think the two statements make the intention clearer.